# Bootstrap image changes size

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap 2.2.2 and it seems that my image in the "hero" div resizes perfectly on page load, then reacts for some reason and expands to be larger than the div and gets cut off.

See page here: http://www.thelocalgolfer.com/mobile/index2.php

Please note I am using a jquery plugin for tooltips over each state.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is:
This div in span 5 have height 298px and width 454px.
The canvas is inside this div having height 328px and width 500px.

So whats happening is , canvas is loaded after div so its giving you Zoom effect.

solution: Makes height and width of both same, so it will work nicely.

Comment: I have looked more in to the issue, it appears that this has to do with the jquery map highlight and a conflict with bootstrap.  The issue doesn't present itself on FF or Chrome, but on IE and mobile devices the zoom issue still occurs.  I cannot statically set the image because they are dynamically loaded.